# Testing the serialization of a class

Tags: java, security, serialization

I have created a `Serializable` class. It is to be used in a desktop application. Are there a set of standard/commonly-used tests which I should write to test the class's serialization and deserialization process.

It is expected that the class may change in future, but byte-code should be kept compatible between versions.

The security of the application in which the class is used *is* important: it must be able to handle crafted byte-streams.

If there are any commonly used tests, a brief mention of the purpose of each would be useful [what aspect of serialization do each address].

Comment: I can remove the last statement if it is considered too open ended.

Comment: If the class will change and the serialized data must remain compatible, then consider using JAXB or JSON or something similar to serialize your data. Then your tests will just be simple parsing tests testing the parsing both of older serialized versions and of newer.

Comment: ...also, define 'security of the application'... does this mean the data must be encrypted? the parsers must handle bad data nicely? the parsers must remain backward compatible?

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to avoid using default serialization for long-term storage, especially in applications where you suspect the serialized class may change significantly. Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear on what's being serialized. Perhaps we can see some code?

The serialization system doesn't have any built-in security. You could encrypt the stored data, of course. Again, we need more information about the application.

As far as testing goes, its a good idea to save serialized instances from every version of the serializable class as you modify it, and attempt to load them in individual unit tests, checking the fields to ensure they were loaded correctly. Note that simply serializing and deserializing an instance in one test isn't very useful, although you should probably do it anyway.